# Proving density of mα + n | m ∈ Z, n ∈ N where α is irrational

Tags: real-analysis

Let α be an irrational number. Fix an interval (a,b). Show that it contains a number of the form mα + n, where m ∈ Z and n ∈ N. Without loss, assume a > 0 (otherwise we can add a positive integer).

I tried this problem by first proving that for any 0<r<(b-a) there exists an integer multiple of r in (a,b).
Also I chose r = mα + n such that 0 < mα + n < 1/k , where m ∈ Z and k
,n ∈ N and 1/k<(b-a). Then i can say that some integer multiple of this would be present in (a,b) and proof would be complete.
But i am not able to prove the existance of r in (0,1/k). Can someone please help me with this?

Also if I am proving the density the incorrect way can one please tell the correct way to prove it?

Comment: Your approach is fine. The part which is troubling you is handled already on math.se. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857029/72031 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3559451/72031

Comment: This is a particular case of [KAT](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).